# I am trying to create a camera app and i having problem with the capture button. When i click on the button it not working

Tags: kotlin

I have tried much code for takephoto function but still not working please help.

```
val photofile =
            File(externalMediaDirs.firstOrNull(), "CameraX - ${System.currentTimeMillis()}.jpg")
val output = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(photofile).build()

imageCapture?.takePicture(
    output, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
        override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Image Capture Succesfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Image Capture Failed!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Please add Android tag -- kotlin have grater use

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

check if u have permission to take a photo and to save file in the storage:
In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

And then request permissions, for example:

```
try {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), 123)
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        /* YOUR CODE HERE */
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```